# Node JS premature program end

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I call a function that stacks two async calls and calls a callback when they have both completed.
 I am using a really simple method to keep track of the calls that have not completed 
lock++
lock--
The problem is that the program exits before the operation of the two functions is complete. I noticed this was the problem when I was debugging and gave the process time to complete before it exits.
 
 How can I fix this? (At the moment I am at a bit of a loss on how to exactly explain my problem please ask me anything you need to so I can clarify the question)

-----EDIT

With the script below why when I run it does it just exit? I thought that by calling on I was registering to the event que and the script should continue to run?

```
var events  = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

eventEmitter.on('spo',function(){
console.log('spo');
});
```

Comment: Post some sample code?

Comment: You can try and use https://github.com/caolan/async . Does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[COMING From a Git Hub thread.](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2730#issuecomment-3906675)

> What keeps the event loop alive is handles (sockets, timers, etc.) of which your script has none.
>
> EventEmitter instances are synchronous - that is, they run immediately
>   - so in your example, once the event has fired, the script is done.
>
> Think of it like this: an EventEmitter in itself isn't useful, it only
>   becomes useful when it's tied to something that emits interesting
>   events (data from the network or the file system, a timer that
>   expires, etc.).

I think that what they are saying is that it is the handle outside of Node into C land that holds the script open.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you setup an event emitter and attach a handler to the "spo" event and then you do nothing else.  So the node runtime sees that there is nothing left to do and exits.  Try this:

```javascript
eventEmitter.on('spo', function() {
  console.log('OK: got event "spo"');
});
eventEmitter.emit('spo');
```

Comment: It runs the callback then still exits.  The way I was understanding it is that as long as there was a registered listener the event loop wont exit!  What if I want something to function like http.listen(); which keeps the script running.

Comment: setInterval(function(){},500); Will keep it running but I feel like that should not be needed.

Comment: @JamesAndino: right, if you use `setInterval()` then node knows that something might emit an event in the future since there is something in the event queue; however, when the event queue is empty, it just exits.  I suppose that functions like `httpServer.listen()` add a "permanent" entry to the event queue so that node doesn't exit, not sure of the specifics though.